# Angular 2 - How to set id attribute to the dynamically loaded component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `DynamicComponentLoader` to load the child component and it produces the following html:

```
<child-component> Child content here </child-component>
```

and here is how I am loading the component in the parent

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
        this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'child');
  }
```

How can I add the id attribute to the child component so that it produces the following html:

```
<child-component id="someId" > Child content here </child-component>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If possible I would add a field to `ChildComponent` and bind `id` to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  host: {'[id]': 'id'}
})
class ChildComonent {
  id:string;
}
```

```
this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'child')
.then(cmp => cmp.instance.id = 'someId');
```

See also http://plnkr.co/edit/ihb7dzRlz1DO5piUvoXw?p=preview#

A more hacky way would be

```
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Dynamic, this.ref, 'child').then((cmp) => {
  cmp.location.nativeElement.id = 'someId';
});
```

Instead of accessing `nativeElement` properties directly it should be possible to do the same with `Renderer`.

Comment: what does the host: {'attr.id': 'id'} do?

Comment: It sets the `id` attribute of the `<child-component>` tag to the value of `this.id`.

Comment: But the syntax in the answer is wrong (correct in the Plunker) but  `attr.` is redundant because `it` is a property on any element and reflected to the `id` attribute automatically. Updated my answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please show how to do the same but for multiple css classes? eg. <my-component class="container container--large"></my-component>

Comment: Just search for how to add classes in JS

Comment: FYI, My TSLint recommends the `@HostBinding` over the host component parameter, this syntax looks like this for me     `@HostBinding('attr.id') id;`  this goes within the component just like an `@Input` parameter would

Comment: The Angular team says that they are equivalent. Tslint has its own opinion ;-)