# Angular2 DynamicComponentLoader

Tags: angular

Using any method (ex. loadIntoLocation) I can dynamically load a directive into my basic component to a specific container !

```
@Component({ ... template: ` <div #elementContainer>empty div</div>` ...})
```

then by calling

```
this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DirectiveClass, this._elementRef, 'elementContainer')
```

I will pass to the empty div the template of a DirectiveClass like:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
```

so the final result will be an empty div plus my input element!

The question is: how to change the value attribute or any other of the input value also dynamically by calling loadIntoLocation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

`loadIntoLocation()` was removed from `DynamicComponentLoader`. Use instead `loadNextToLocation()` with `ViewContainerRef`

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  top;

  constructor(private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(DynamicComponent, this.target)
    .then(ref => {
      ref.instance.someEvent
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.top = value.clientX; 
      })
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example beta.16**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CcKXhq?p=preview)

**original**

This looks quite similar to [Angular 2 - How to set id attribute to the dynamically loaded component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703379/angular-2-how-to-set-id-attribute-to-the-dynamically-loaded-component) that I recently answered

You don't explain how you add the input.

```ts
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(DirectiveClass, this._elementRef, 'elementContainer').then((cmp) => {
  cmp.location.nativeElement.querySelector('input').value = 'someId';
});
```

might do what you want (not tested).

Comment: Input is another directive component imported in main component so it's displayed only when necessary!

Comment: That doesn't really help. Can you add the code to your question how you add it? Maybe you can derive the solution for your case anyway from my answer.