# Remove the margin of an element using angular

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to remove the margin from an element. This margin is generated by ionic 
this is the element where I want to remove the margin from:

I'm in `page-table-view` it's the subpage of `page-board`

[image]

I tried to remove the margin with this code:

```
   if (document.querySelector('.scroll-content')) {
       this.scrollContentElements = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-content');    
   }

   if (this.scrollContentElements) {    
       this.scrollContentElements[1].style.marginTop = '0';
       this.scrollContentElements[1].style.marginBottom = '0';
   }
```

When I do `console.log(this.scrollContentElements)` I find this:

```
outerHTML:"<div class="scroll-content" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">↵↵</div>"
```

**But no changes in the view**

How can I solve this issue?

**NOTE:**

Changing the `CSS` like this:

```
.scroll-content {    
    margin-top:0px !important;
}
```

Changes this page but also changes all the other pages.

Comment: Make the CSS-rule specifik to the element?

Comment: this element is generated I can't see it in my code

Comment: You should put this only in your component's stylesheet

Comment: yes I put it in my component stylesheet

Comment: then, to the concerned element give an id and do #yourid{ margin....}

Comment: this element is generated I don't have access to it in my code

Comment: Why do you need access to it in your component class?

Comment: because I don't have problem in other pages . I can't add css style to fix it because page-table-view is inside page-board so I don't have another choice

Comment: Note that other elements in that page I can change there style in angular code. but this element doesn't change

Comment: how about setting like this      this.scrollContentElements[1].setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 0px !important");

Comment: Pages doesn't nest. They become siblings.

Comment: @Vega the same thing nothing change

Comment: and how about .page-board:first-child{margin..} ?

Comment: and I would try what I said about give an id and styling accordingly with the answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703379/angular-2-how-to-set-id-attribute-to-the-dynamically-loaded-component

Comment: Since the CSS-example in your question has an effect on all pages, one must draw the conclusion that you, with specificity, can affect only the desired page. So please look in to your CSS instead of programatically adding styles in your component class code. For your own sake!

Comment: @Vega page-board:first-child{margin..} also doesn't make changement

Comment: @robbannn yes it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

**SASS**

```
page-board {
    .scroll-content {
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

**[CSS-specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**
'Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.' - MDN

Comment: Is this css? or sass?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but page-board is the parent page I don't want to change it css style I'm in 'page-table-view' it's the subpage

Comment: In your screenshot its looks like `page-board` is the current page though.

Comment: @Vega its SASS. The CSS equivalent is `page-board .scroll-content {...`

Comment: @robbannn, thank you for the explanation. I didn't tell I don't know what it is, otherwise I would've recognise it. I told you that your statement CSS is maybe not completely correct!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you please elaborate?